# Windows Phone read the accounts of the owner

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8, gmail, windows-phone, windows-live-id

I am making an app for Windows Phone 8 and I want to know if I can read the phone owner's accounts programmatically, such as windows live id, gmail, facebook and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, users have to authenticate with all of those again in your app.

Comment: So, is impossible to get these accounts as is. I wanted to make an app which need to retrieve these accounts. So, definitely is impossible right?

Comment: There are system tasks for sharing statuses etc. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394027(v=vs.105).aspx) but no, you don't have access to user's social accounts data from inside your app unless your implement it all by yourself.